# preventing actioncable subscribers from submitting messages to chatrooms that they are not a part of in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

If my app uses AJAX to submit a user's `message` to a server side `speak` method that has no need for a controller (and therefore no space to write a `before_filter`), how would I implement behavior that restricts `users` who are not a part of that `conversation` from submitting messages through the browser console?

If I open my app and type `App.messages.speak("hi", #guess random number#)` that message is submitted to the conversation whether they are a part of it or not.

**messages_channel.rb**

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 def speak(data)
  Message.create! body: data['body'], conversation_id: data['conversation_id'], user_id: current_user.id
 end
end
```

**messages.coffee**

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create "MessagesChannel", 
 speak: (body, conversation_id) ->
  @perform 'speak', body: body, conversation_id: conversation_id

 submit_message = () ->
 $('#response').on 'keydown', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13
    conversation_id = $("[data-conversation-id]").data("conversation-id")
    App.messages.speak(event.target.value, conversation_id)
    event.target.value = ""
    event.preventDefault()
```

I'm thinking I could remove the `conversation_id` param from the `speak` method and set it elsewhere that isn't dependent on user input? Currently I have it set as a data attribute, which means people could still mess with it.

Comment: What is generating data-conversation-id in the first place? You can always use long uuids that are unguessable but I'm not sure that's the correct way to use channels

Comment: It's a data attribute in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a callback.

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
 before_create :exclude_non_participants

 def exclude_non_participants
  if conversation.participates?(user)
   true
  else
   throw :abort
  end
 end
end
```

`participates?(user)` in this case is:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
 def participates?(user)
 sender == user || receiver == user
 end
end
```

If there's a better way to do this, please let me know. For now, I think this works?